# Making a Video Source a Variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a video that I want to create as a variable so I can insert it into the HTML string. This is what I have right now.

Variable:

```
var vids = 'big_buck_bunny.mp4';
```

HTML string:

```
'<source type="video/mp4" src="videos/' + vids + '" />'
```

When I refresh the browser it does not find the video

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a *`"`*, at the end of `src="videos/`,  or at least, have mismatched quotes somewhere.

Comment: @user2958098 I'm not very familiar with JavaScript, so I can't answer definitively. It just seems to be that you need another single *'* before `videos/` and remove the code after `vids`. Ex: `src="'videos/'` to specify the videos/ directory, then ` + vids '` to specify the variable. Combine those two and you would have `src="'videos/' + vids "`

Comment: @user2958098 Check out [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234533/how-do-i-concatenate-a-string-with-a-variable-javascript) and [this question, too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554928/add-javascript-variable-to-javascript-src/)

Comment: @user2958098 Can you post what ended up working for you? Just in case anyone else has the same/similar issue. Glad you were able to get it to work!

Comment: I fully qualified the url var vids = 'http://localhost/ExpandableVideoUnit/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4'; and then I put it above the hhtml string '<source type="video/mp4" src="' + vids + '" />' and it worked