# How can I use a variable in a script tag source attribute?

Tags: javascript

is it possible to do something like this,
(really new to js, just wondering if something like this is possbile couldn't find anything on the internet.)

```
<script>
var url="Pastebin.com"
var extra="/74205
</script>

<script src=url+extra></script>
```

Thank you.

Comment: The source cannot be variables by default as the source file is the script itself. I see you have very well explained options in answers below.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can give your script tag an id:

```
<script id="myScript"></script>
```

and then set the src attribute to your desired value:

```
<script>
  var url="Pastebin.com";
  var extra="/74205";
  document.getElementById('myScript').src = url+extra;
</script>
```

the script tag with id (myScript) should appear first in page in order for `document.getElementById` to work

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is : NO

However, as you already have the required url to attach to the `<script>` tag's source attribute, this can be accomplished with the help of javascript itself.

First, we are going to create a script tag, and then modify its src attribute to point to the URL. Then, simply attach it to the required element with id, say, "foo"

```
<script>

  var url="Pastebin.com"
  var extra="/74205"
  var parent = document.getElementById("foo")
  var someScriptElement = document.createElement("script")
  someScriptElement.setAttribute("src",url+extra)
  foo.appendChild(someScriptElement)

</script>
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

you will find the answer to your question in:

[Add javascript variable to javascript src?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554928/add-javascript-variable-to-javascript-src)

and

[Use JS variable to set the src attribute for <script> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150409/use-js-variable-to-set-the-src-attribute-for-script-tag)

Answer (score 1):

yes it's possible

```js
<script>
  var url="http://pastebin.com";
  var extra="/74205";

  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src = url + extra
  document.body.appendChild(script);
</script>
```